# Is there a way to force a single digit Int into a two digit int value?

Tags: android, integer, int, digit

I need to show time in my app. i am storing the hour and minutes values in the form of integer to the database. all works fine, but I dislike it when a value drops to a single digit as it is meant to look like a 4 value clock. By this I mean, if the time is 6 hours and 3 minutes it outputs "6:3" when if it is 11 hours and 11 minutes it outputs"11:11". I would like it to always display 4 numbers regardless of the value.

**WHAT HAPPENS :**

> 6:3 AM (6 hours 3 minutes)
>
> 11:11 AM (11 hours 11 minutes)

**WHAT I WANT**

> 6:03 AM (6 hours 3 minutes)
>
> 4:08 PM ( 4 hour 8 minutes )
>
> 11:11 AM (11 hours 11 minutes)

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you save time in you db by using System.currentTimeMillis() method and then convert it in whatever form you wish with the help of Date/Calendar library??

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is [String formatting](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)).

For example, `String.format("%02d", minutes)` to format `minutes` as integer with 2 digits, left-padding with zeros as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
private String getMinutesInTwoDigits(String time) {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormatGiven = new SimpleDateFormat("h:m a");
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormatRequired = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a");
    String result = null;
    try {
        result = dateFormatRequired.format(dateFormatGiven.parse(time));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        return time;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: thank you but as i can see you considered the given date format as h:m but that could be hh:mm too...  @JunaidKhan